# hover won't work on child link

Tags: html, css

Excuse my style sheet. I can't make a specific section i.e. `.hot-menu` change color on hover. It is seeming to only use the page hover. I have tried several options, none are working. The web page is at:

```
http://tahoe-luxury-properties.com/index4.html
```

The top left navigation menu that starts with "Home" won't change on hover to this green color that I like i.e. `#73AD21`.

The css that is controlling that menu for the most part is:

```
.hot-menu {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica;
    line-height: 20px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    border-bottom-width: fit-content;
    margin: 5px 10px; /* <-- Fix */
    padding: 7px 0px; /* <-- Fix */
    hover: #73AD21 !important;
 }

 li a {
     border-bottom: 4px solid #0CF;
     padding: 7px 0px;
 }
```

I have tried adding the green into the #, inline, the li and can't get it. You smart people always seem to help. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. -Beth

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify like this:

```
.hot-menu a:hover {
    color: #73AD21;
}
```

No need for !important

also `:hover` is a pseudo class and can't be used like you've set it up

Looking at your code you could also simplify it, instead of:

```
<li>
  <p>
    <span>
      <a>Link</a>
    </span>
  </p>
</li>
```

Just write

```
<li>
  <a>Link</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Hello Wim Mertens - The very first item worked. I feel like I tried that, but I guess not. Very weird how I can't get these little things to work? Thank You.

Comment: @bethabernathy that's because you have added the styles to .hot-menu.
In fact you don't need that, you could just declare it in your ul: ul class="hot-menu" and then style .hot-menu li and .hot-menu li a

Comment: I see your ul has already a class horizontal-tabs so just use that for styling :)